# Java 8 map to only value type collection

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, collectors

I want to convert my `Map <K,V>` into only a `Set <V>`. I could not find any example anywhere, including Oracle's documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html
All I could go further is:

```
myMap.entrySet().parallelStream().
                filter((entry) -> entry.getKey().startsWith("a"))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This returns a Set of `Map.Entry`. In this example it's `Map<String, String>` so I would only expect it to return the value bit (String), I have tried `.collect(Collectors.toSet(HashMap::getValue))` but that didn't work. So what am I missing here?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `values()` returns `Collections<V>` I also need to convert that into a set, which I find it a little ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add one more step to map to values:

```
myMap.entrySet().parallelStream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("a"))
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: You can use a method reference